# Django IntegerRangeField Error binding parameter probably unsupported type

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I`m trying to replace year_from and year_to fields by year field which is IntegerRangeField in my model, but getting error while adding new object in admin.

The issue is "Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type."
Can anybody take a look for a while and help? Thanks in advance!

*models.py*

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models


class Bancnote(models.Model):

    DOLLAR = 'Dollar'
    EURO = 'Euro'

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (DOLLAR , 'Dollar'),
        (EURO, 'Euro')
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, 
                            default=DOLLAR )
    par = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year_from = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year_to = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = IntegerRangeField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bons_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.par) + ' ' + self.type + ' ' + str(self.year_from) + 
                   '-' + str(self.year_to)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like IntegerRangeField is PostgreSQL specific form field ([IntegerRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#integerrangefield)). Let us know if You're using PostgreSQL.

Comment: my bad, was using sqlite3 as default, working fine now on postgresql. Thanks a lot!